# normalisation constant of SE for infinite square well

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

we fix arbitrary constant A by normalizing wave function $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{a}|A|^2sin^2(kx)dx = 1$

by using identity $sin^2(x) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} cos{2x}$ we can rearrange integral to $|A|^2 \displaystyle \int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} cos{2kx}dx$ = $|A|^2 \displaystyle \int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{2}(1- cos{2kx})dx$ = $\displaystyle \frac {|A|^2}{2}\int_{0}^{a}(1- cos{2kx})dx = \displaystyle \frac {|A|^2}{2}(a-\frac{sin2ka}{2k})=1$

since normalisation constant is $\displaystyle A=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$

The question is where does sine term gone?

Comment: The wave function is constrained within $[0,a]$ and hence vanishes at the boundary (i.e. at $0$ and $a$).

Comment: you mean sine term at a is = 0?

Comment: yes, the wave function are linear combination of those $\sin(kx)$ satisfying $\sin(ka) = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you found your wave functions you had two boundary conditions to satisfy, $\Psi(x) = Asin(kx) + B cos(kx)$ which were $\Psi(0) = \Psi(a) = 0$.  Imposing these gave B=0 and $ka=n\pi$ so $k=\frac{n\pi}{a}$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.  So $sin(2ka)=sin(2n\pi)=0$, so as @achille hui said it's because of your boundary conditions.

Comment: I missed that my $k=\displaystyle \frac {n\pi}{a}$ Thank you!